# Extending the Boolean Object in Javascript with an 'invert' function

Tags: javascript, boolean, prototype-programming

I would like to extend the Boolean object with a prototype function that inverts it's current value. Until now, I've been doing something like this:

```
var bool = true;
bool = !bool;
console.log(bool);  // false
```

My attempts at extending the Boolean object were not fruitful. That's how far I got:

```
Boolean.prototype.invert = function() {
    return !this.valueOf();
}

var bool = true;
bool = bool.invert();
console.log(bool);  // false
```

Close, but not close enough. I am looking for a solution along these lines:

```
var bool = true;
bool.invert();
console.log(bool);  // false
```

*Yes, I know, extending build-in Object is commonly considered a bad idea. Please let's save that discussion for another day.*

Comment: What's the point though, besides the fact you are trying to mutate state, what would be the purpose of this other than trying to avoid a simple reassignment: `bool = !bool;`?

Comment: Maybe I should rephrase the question: How can I mutate the state of an object with a prototype... Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4066094/change-value-of-a-wrapped-primitive-data-type

Answer (score 5):

Scalar values are immutable in all oop languages, you need a new class

```
var BooleanBuilder = function( data ){ this._data = !!data; };

BooleanBuilder.prototype.valueOf = function() {
    return this._data;
};
BooleanBuilder.prototype.invert = function() {
    this._data = !this._data;
};

var bool = new BooleanBuilder(true);
alert(bool.valueOf());
bool.invert();
alert(bool.valueOf());  // false
```

but this is not so smart, you can store the boolean-value in one object and pass this object as reference